# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element' while testing opening encrypted epubs

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, epub, web-testing, testcafe

While attempting to open encrypted epubs using TestCafe I consistently get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.`

`In browser mode, the script shows the browser throwing this error:  error in line 10 at column 8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head`

I found this possible reason:

`XHTML does not support document.write or .innerHTML. Due to the fact, that jQuery inserts the new code using one of these methods, all XHTML compatible browsers will error out`

Does this mean that I cannot use TestCafe at all to do this kind of operation?

The code I am using is a simple .click(bookselector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe can test HTML pages only. Your browser can treat EPUB files as pages when you click on a link because EPUB format is very similar to XML and HTML. Instead of clicking on a link to an EPUB file, consider retrieving the URL via the `href` and use [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) or [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) to download the file.